# How to detect if turtle is in the radius of x & y and then do something?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Currently, I'm trying to make a game and in the game I would like it so if the character is on top of an object, it picks it up. This is what I have so far:

```
import turtle
import time

default = turtle.clone()
scar = turtle.clone()

def pickupScar():
    if default.distance(-7,48) > 5.0:
        default.changeshape('defaultscar.gif')

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(500,500)
wn.bgpic('TrumpTowers.gif')
wn.register_shape('default.gif')
wn.register_shape('scar.gif')
wn.register_shape('defaultscar.gif')

turtle.hideturtle()
default.shape('default.gif')
scar.shape('scar.gif')

default.pu()
default.left(90)
default.bk(35)

scar.pu()
scar.left(90)
scar.fd(45)
scar.speed(-1)

default.ondrag(default.goto)
```

Does anybody know how I would go with making the def pickupScar as I'm new to python & turtle. If you recognize what my game is about please don't judge me, it's for a school project and I couldn't think of any game ideas.

Comment: please detail a little more your issue, @MistxOli.

Comment: So you have a (x,y) coordinate and you'd like to find the radius from turtle to this point, is it right?

Comment: @LuanNaufal its not an issue i was wondering how i would detect if the turtle was in the radius of x & y and if it was to do something.

Comment: Stack overflow is for specific programming questions. This question will most likely be closes. But as you seem to be a new user: There is a `distance` function in `turtle`. And maybe you want to look at `threading` if you need to poll, but maybe `turtle` has a built-in event for this

Comment: @LuanNaufal no i would like for the game to detect if the turtle goes in lets say a 10px radius of a set x y.

Comment: @user8408080 could i make it so if the turtle was in a >10 distance from x & y it does something like change the turtles shape?

Comment: I'm no turtle/tkinter expert. What I would do is: Write a function, that checks distance every x miliseconds and if the distance meets a certain condition, do something. I then would start this function in a seperate thread. I could give you an example later this evening, but i'm busy for now. Maybe somebody else will have posted it by then

Comment: @user8408080 I've updated the post with my code, can you tell me what I've done wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have your images, nor recognize what your game is about, below is an example of the functionality you describe.  On the screen is a black circle and pink square.  You can drag the circle and if you drag it onto the square, it will sprout a head and legs becoming a turtle.  Dragging off the square, it reverts to being a circle:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def drag(x, y):
    default.ondrag(None)  # disable handler inside handler

    default.goto(x, y)

    if default.distance(scar) < 40:
        default.shape('turtle')
    elif default.shape() == 'turtle':
        default.shape('circle')

    default.ondrag(drag)

wn = Screen()
wn.setup(500, 500)

scar = Turtle('square', visible=False)
scar.shapesize(4)
scar.color('pink')
scar.penup()
scar.left(90)
scar.forward(50)
scar.showturtle()

default = Turtle('circle', visible=False)
default.shapesize(2)
default.speed('fastest')
default.penup()
default.left(90)
default.backward(50)
default.showturtle()

default.ondrag(drag)

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: The center part should also be a circle, so the radius is clear

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the `turtle-graphics`, but in real world to determine the distance between two points (for 2D surfaces) we use **Pythagorean theorem**.

If some object is at `(x1, y1)` and another at `(x2, y2)`, the distance is

```
dist=sqrt((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2)
```

So, if `dist <= R`, turtle (or whatever) is `in R radius from desired point`

Comment: OP asked for event detection rather than just calculating distance