# turtle definition looks ok to me but doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Currently, I'm trying to make a game and in the game I would like it so if the character is on top of an object, it picks it up. This is what I have so far:

```
import turtle
import time

default = turtle.clone()
scar = turtle.clone()

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(500,500)
wn.bgpic('TrumpTowers.gif')
wn.register_shape('default.gif')
wn.register_shape('scar.gif')
wn.register_shape('defaultscar.gif')

def drag(x, y):
    default.ondrag(None)  # disable handler inside handler

    default.goto(x, y)

    if default.distance(scar) < 40:
        default.shape('defaultscar.gif')
    elif default.shape() == 'turtle':
        default.shape('circle')

    default.ondrag(drag)

turtle.hideturtle()
default.shape('default.gif')
scar.shape('scar.gif')

default.pu()
default.left(90)
default.bk(35)

scar.pu()
scar.left(90)
scar.fd(45)
scar.speed(-1)

default.ondrag(default.goto)
```

Does anybody know how I would go with fixing this as it looks ok to me, but doesn't actually work!

Comment: Please upload all the `.gif` image files being used somewhere, like [imgur](https://imgur.com/), and then [edit] your question and put links to each of them in it. That way you'll be more likely to get answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three issues in your code.  First, you're calling `hideturtle()` on a turtle you're not really using:

```
turtle.hideturtle()
```

This is being applied to the default turtle which shouldn't be in play.  It only shows up, and gets in the way, because you do:

```
default = turtle.clone()
scar = turtle.clone()
```

Instead of:

```
default = turtle.Turtle()
scar = turtle.Turtle()
```

The `speed()` method does not recognize an argument of -1:

```
scar.speed(-1)
```

It will set it to a different value if the argument isn't valid.

Finally, where you're likely having the problem you're asking about, you include the definition of `drag(x, y)` [I wrote for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53583311/5771269) but when it comes time to set a handler, you set the wrong function:

```
default.ondrag(default.goto)
```

it should be:

```
default.ondrag(drag)
```